# How I can improve my snippet with additional logic for the faster creation of the C# + Playwright test with description in the Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, playwright, code-snippets

I created a snippet for the creation of a C# + Playwright test with a description in the Visual Studio. When using the "pwtest" shortcut and pressing the 'Tab' key, you will be prompted to enter a method description. The description you input should be used as both the method's name and description. But if the description contains spaces I want to replace that with one word using camel case.
For example, if you input "Sample description" as the description, the template should generate the following code:

```
    [Test, Description("Sample description")] 
    public async Task SampleDescription() 
    { // Arrange
    
    // Act
    
    // Assert 
    }
```

My snippet:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">   <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
          <SnippetTypes>
            <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
          </SnippetTypes>
          <Title>Test Playwright Method with Description</Title>
          <Shortcut>pwtest</Shortcut>
          <Description>Adds a test method with a description for Playwright</Description>
          <Author>Ivan</Author>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
          <Imports>
            <Import>
              <Namespace>Microsoft.Playwright</Namespace>
            </Import>
          </Imports>
          <Declarations>
            <Literal>
              <ID>description</ID>
              <ToolTip>Description</ToolTip>
              <Default>Sample description</Default>
            </Literal>
          </Declarations>
          <Code Language="csharp">
            <![CDATA[[Test, Description("$description$")] 
            public async Task $description$()
            {
             // Arrange

             // Act
    
             // Assert
            }
            ]]>
          </Code>
        </Snippet>   </CodeSnippet> </CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.